# Compare two arrays and add new keys based on Index of both Arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I am creating a sunburst chart in highcharts and I am having trouble creating layers in the array.

For instance, the headers array is layer 2 and data array is layer 3.

I need to compare the headername with groups from data and create a new array giving both a child id and a parent id.

Have posted my current solution below the code.

```js
const headers = ['Cars', 'Fruits', 'Food'];

const data = [{
    group: 'Cars',
    name: 'BMW',
    value: '25641'
  }, {
    group: 'Fruits',
    name: 'Apple',
    value: '45876'
  },
  {
    group: 'Cars',
    name: 'Benz',
    value: '65784'
  },
  {
    group: 'Cars',
    name: 'Toyota',
    value: '254'
  },
  {
    group: 'Food',
    name: 'Pizza',
    value: '87535'
  },
  {
    group: 'Cars',
    name: 'Honda',
    value: '65796'
  },
  {
    group: 'Fruits',
    name: 'Banana',
    value: '98631'
  },
  {
    group: 'Fruits',
    name: 'Orange',
    value: '87563'
  },
  {
    group: 'Food',
    name: 'Burger',
    value: '78324'
  },
  {
    group: 'Fruits',
    name: 'Mango',
    value: '24598'
  }
]
```

This is what I tried.

```js
const newArray = headers.map(function(itemA, indexA) {
  return data.map(function(itemB, indexB) {
  return {
    id: `3.${indexB + 1}`,
    parentId: `2.${indexA + 1}`,
    value: itemB.value,
    name: itemB.name
  }
  })
})
```

This is the output I expect:

```js
const newArray = [{
    id: '3.1',
    parentId: '2.1',
    name: 'BMW',
    value: '25641'
  }, {
    id: '3.2',
    parentId: '2.2',
    name: 'Apple',
    value: '45876'
  },
  {
    id: '3.3',
    parentId: '2.1',
    name: 'Benz',
    value: '65784'
  },
  {
    id: '3.4',
    parentId: '2.1'
    name: 'Toyota',
    value: '254'
  },
  {
    id: '3.5',
    parentId: '2.3',
    name: 'Pizza',
    value: '87535'
  },
  {
    id: '3.6',
    parentId: '2.1',
    name: 'Honda',
    value: '65796'
  },
  {
    id: '3.7',
    parentId: '2.2',
    name: 'Banana',
    value: '98631'
  },
  {
    id: '3.8',
    parentId: '2.2',
    name: 'Orange',
    value: '87563'
  },
  {
    id: '3.9',
    parentId: '2.3',
    name: 'Burger',
    value: '78324'
  },
  {
    id: '3.10',
    parentId: '2.2',
    name: 'Mango',
    value: '24598'
  }
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need the nested maps — it will cause nested arrays of results. You just need one because there is a 1-to1 relationship between `data` and your expected output. You can just `map()` over data and lookup the parent index as you go.

```js
const headers = ['Cars', 'Fruits', 'Food'];

const data = [{group: 'Cars',name: 'BMW',value: '25641'}, {group: 'Fruits',name: 'Apple',value: '45876'},{group: 'Cars',name: 'Benz',value: '65784'},{group: 'Cars',name: 'Toyota',value: '254'},{group: 'Food',name: 'Pizza',value: '87535'},{group: 'Cars',name: 'Honda',value: '65796'},{group: 'Fruits',name: 'Banana',value: '98631'},{group: 'Fruits',name: 'Orange',value: '87563'},{group: 'Food',name: 'Burger',value: '78324'},{group: 'Fruits',name: 'Mango',value: '24598'}]

const newArray = data.map(function(itemB, indexB) {
    let parentIndex = headers.indexOf(itemB.group) // just find the parent index
    return {
      id: `3.${indexB + 1}`,
      parentId: `2.${parentIndex + 1}`,
      value: itemB.value,
      name: itemB.name
    }
    })

console.log(newArray)
```